# Floating unequal height divs side by side

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create floating divs as mentioned in the below picture (uploaded on the below link), I am using float left to move all divs side by side.

[image: Picture]

First picture has the default divs,

when we click on the div its height expands, as mentioned in second picture third div should come exactly below the first one without disturbing other divs, as mentined in third picture same as second picture when we click on second div the fourth div should float bottom and should not disturb other divs. First, second and third picture has four divs but the divs can be of any number. In fourth picture we have only three divs and when we click on 1st div third div should move right side and it should happen the same when we have five or seven divs. How i can perform this task by using css?

Comment: You should not be using floats to accomplish this. What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: please show us your attempts so far.

Comment: It would be advantageous to use jQuery to complete this.

Comment: dont think you can cover all of these options with simple css. for instance the second example should work if you have the third div clear:left; but not at the fourth example

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use Javascript/JQuery if you want click events to grow the size of the DIVs.
I wouldn't recommend floats - here's a quick pointer using inline-block instead. You could use flexbox but it depends what browsers you need to support?

http://jsbin.com/domokefipi/1/edit

Comment: Thanks Ali for the great efforts, but I can't achieve the goal mention in fourth picture using this. It works fine if we have four divs but when we have three divs the third div should float right in the empty area when we click on first div.

Comment: Ahh I see - that makes it a bit more complicated! Have you looked into plugins like Masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/) or are you keeping it all custom?

Comment: Yes I checked that plugin but I was trying to make it using simple JQuery and CSS, without using any plugin.